# Show redshift queries using aws command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-redshift

How can I see the stats about queries similar to what one can see in the `queries` tab within the aws console at the cluster panel but using a shell based tool like aws-cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although some answers were really close, the queries that appear in the `queries` tab in the redshift console is at `pg_catalog.stv_recents`. Having `psql` installed, one can query that by executing:

```
psql $connection_string \
    --command="select * from pg_catalog.stv_recents order by starttime desc;"
```

Comment: this table seems to only have about 5 seconds worth of data in it

Answer (score 2):

The information about queries executed in Amazon Redshift are stored in System Tables.

See: [STL Tables for Logging - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_intro_STL_tables.html)

It is not possible to access this information via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). You will need to use an SQL client (eg `psql`) to connect to Redshift to be able to query these tables.